# Mustache variable declaring

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, mustache, declare

```
var page = {
    pageCount : 3,
    pageNum : [
        //loop script to create '"num" : "x"'
    ]
};
var pageTemplate = '{{#pageNum}} <div id="page{{num}}" class="pages"> page {{num}} </div> {{/pageNum}}';
var pageHtml = Mustache.to_html(pageTemplate, page);
```

Is it possible to create a for loop or some sort to create num variables in accordance to pageCount like this:

for (var x = 0; x <= pageCount; x++)

It produces a syntax error so I want to know if there are other alternatives to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js):

> **Enumerable Sections**
>
> [...] Use `{{.}}` to access the current item inside the enumeration section.

So all you need to do is put the numbers in `pageNum`:

```
var page = {
    pageCount : 3,
    pageNum : [ ]
};
for(var i = 0; i < page.pageCount; ++i)
    page.pageNum[i] = i + 1;
```

And then use `{{.}}` to access them in the template:

```
{{#pageNum}} <div id="page{{.}}" class="pages"> page {{.}} </div> {{/pageNum}}
```